# use "nohup &" always get [1]+ Exit 1 after ENTER

Tags: virtualbox, nohup

Hi I'm using `nohup command-name &` recently.

My issue is:
[image: Terminal screen]

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will show `[1]+  Exit 1`. and can't finish the command.
How can I run the second command while I'm running `nohup`?

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the commands using `;` (second command would be independent of the first) or `&&` (second would be run only if the first one succeeds).

Then, you need to use the shell with command grouping or use a subshell to make the commands as one (only shell) to `nohup` and run the commands inside the shell process:

```
nohup bash -c '{ command_1 && command_2 ;}' &
```

Or

```
nohup bash -c '( command_1 && command_2 )' &
```

Comment: which means I can't type ENTER before "nohup command-name &" finish?

Comment: @JingNing I don't understand. Didn't you need to run two commands from one go of `nohup`?

Comment: No, For example, I run the first command in "nohup first-command &", then I have the second command outside of "nohup first-command &" (like pwd ls cd and so on).  Could I run the second command while I'm running the "nohup first-command &"?

Comment: @JingNing That depends on how much time the first command lasts for. See if `nohup command_1 &; command_2` works..

Comment: Hi heemayl, the first command lasts more than one hour.

Comment: @JingNing check the command I've given in the earlier comment..that should do then..